# Colorbox - Change the image numbering to sequenced

Tags: slideshow, colorbox

The numbering/monitor of Colorbox for the image slideshow is something like this **"1 of 3"**. I want to make it **" 1 | 2 | 3 "**. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't think of an easy way to do this.  You would have to modify the source of the plugin to provide this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It will need a lot of time for me to modify your code. And I'm not sure if it will go successful. I would like to ask for your help if you have time (I hope I will not disturb you that much). I really need this solution for my boss not to hit me. Anyway, if you cannot give time, its ok sir :) I understand. By the way, this is a very great plugin! :)